# LIKE query sql not working in concatenated values with space

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I have this table

**

```
--------------------------------------------------
| id    | fname       | lname      | age
--------------------------------------------------
| 1     | John        | Smith      | 20
-------------------------------------------------
| 2     | John Craig  | Smith      | 20
-------------------------------------------------- 
| 3     | John Shaw   | Smith      | 20
--------------------------------------------------
```

MYSQL QUERY:

`select id  from person where concat(fname, lname) LIKE = '%johnsmith%'` - this can

select the id
but if there are two words in last name like this:

`select id  from person where concat(fname, lname) LIKE = '%johncraigsmith%'`

it will show no result.

Why?
Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have a space between `john` and `craig`. That would work

```
select id from person 
where replace(concat(fname, lname),' ','') LIKE = '%johncraigsmith%'
```

but that is terrible on performance BTW. Better would be

```
select id from person 
where lname = 'smith'
and fname = 'john craig'
```