# Select 2 concatenated columns in mysql disregarding all spaces

Tags: php, mysql

> Reference: [LIKE query sql not working in concatenated values with space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042236/like-query-sql-not-working-in-concatenated-values-with-space)

Sample table:
**

```
--------------------------------------------------
| id    | fname       | lname        | age
--------------------------------------------------
| 1     | John        | Smith        | 20
-------------------------------------------------
| 2     | John Craig  | De Smith     | 20
-------------------------------------------------- 
| 3     | John        | De Smith     | 20
--------------------------------------------------
```

MYSQL QUERY:

```
SELECT CONCAT(fname,' ',lname) FROM people WHERE CONCAT_WS(first_name,'',last_name) LIKE "%JohnCraigDeSmith%"
```

it will show no result.

How can I build an efficient query for this?

Comment: replace CONCAT_WS with CONCAT in your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(fname, ' ', lname) 
     FROM people 
WHERE CONCAT(REPLACE(fname, ' ', ''), 
REPLACE(lname, ' ', '')) LIKE "%JohnCraigDeSmith%"
```